# Django get a 'sub' object from an objects list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have been countering a problem of retrieving a 'sub' objects from an objects list:

```
class BusinessLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, related_name='user_business_likes')
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='business_likes')
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'business'),)
```

How do I get `'Business'` object for each `'BusinessLike'` object in `app_user.user_businesses_likes` (without looping over the list and making new list with business_like.business)?

Comment: What is `app_user.user_businesses_likes`? What you want exactly to do? can you give more details!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `values` or `values_list`:

```
businesses = BusinessLike.objects.values('business')
businesses = BusinessLike.objects.values_list('business', flat=True)
```

However, this won't give you a list of objects, you only get a list of foreign key ids.

Django doc about [values and value_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

If you want to avoid having additional lookups every time you do `business_like.business`, you could use `select_related`:

```
business_likes = BusinessLike.objects.select_related('business')
```

In this case, when you loop on each `BusinessLike` object and do `business_like.business`, django won't join the database anymore but it's cached in memory already.

[Django doc about select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related).

Comment: how do I make this list of foreign keys to lisst of objects?

Comment: You could do another lookup: `Business.objects.filter(id__in=ids)`, but it's not efficient and we don't usually do it. Because if you have a list of `BusinessLike`, it's the same thing as having a list of `Business` because you have to loop on it at some point anyway, right?

Comment: Well, not exactly as I said, it's not the same thing, but the `__in` should work.

Comment: You are right but i thought there might be an esthetic way of doing it.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No there isn't, or you could look it up from `Business` model instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in the view, you might find it easier to make a new queryset starting with the `Business` model.

```
businesses = Business.objects.filter(business_likes__user=app_user)
```

I'm not sure that you need to create the `BusinessLike` model like this. You could add a many to many field to the `AppUser` model (or the `Business` model if you prefer).

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    business_likes = models.ManyToManyField(Business)
```

Django will take care of creating the intermediate table, and then you can do queries like:

```
businesses = app_user.business_likes.all()
```